# What's the meaning of “Pats bet”

Tags: meaning

It's a quote from the TV drama *Wayne*

Here are the lines:

> -Check it out. Someone got lucky on a **Pats bet** and made rent. Hey, two lucky sons of bitches, huh?

The speaker is Wayne's father who was handing him an envelope filled with money for their house rent. What's the meaning of **Pats bet** here?

Comment: I Googled this because I was watch Wayne too and wanted to find out the meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but my guess is that "Pats" is short for the "Patriots", meaning the American football team the [New England Patriots](https://www.patriots.com/).  This would make sense, as it seems the show is set (at least initially) in Boston, the home town of the Patriots.

So a "Pats bet" is a bet on a game that the Patriots played.